# iOS AFNetworking post request returns Request failed: bad request (400)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-3

I am using AFNetworking to call a post web service, but every time i get the response

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)"

Here is my code

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/json"];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[parameters setObject:self.APIClientID forKey:@"client_id"];
[parameters setObject:self.APIClientSecret forKey:@"client_secret"];
[parameters setObject:self.APIGrantType forKey:@"grant_type"];

[manager POST:self.requestURL
parameters:parameters
  progress:nil
   success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
       success(task, responseObject);
   } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
       failure(task, error);
   }];
```

It works in postman.
[image: Here is the request on postman]
Also, I found lot of answers for similar error, but it solved nothing.

Comment: Did you checked your API in postman first? Did you added App Transport Security Settings in your plist?

Comment: I did, and it works in postman.

Comment: Most probably your request isn't actually exactly like the one you send via Postman. Set the URL to some HTTP url and check the contents of your request with Wireshark or the like, and compare to the same thing sent with Postman.

Comment: Uh, you're sending JSON data with a `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`... That's definitely a sign there's something wrong with your request.

Comment: I checked the request on postman and and the request on my app and they are the same. also, the `Content-Type` is the same as I send it over postman.

Comment: @jcaron I uploaded a screenshot for the request on postman

Comment: No, they're not the same. You're sending JSON. You need to change the `requestSerializer` you use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122613/discussion-between-hesham-haleem-and-jcaron).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `AFJSONRequestSerializer` to serialise your request. This will create a JSON payload and not a url encoded form request.

Try using `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` instead.

Refer to the documentation [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html) for more information.

You can also remove the following line of code as well, the correct request serializer will handle that for you:

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```